# Mapping between button and word for tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, button

While selecting the quantity during order placement I have two buttons, `-` and `+`, which decreases/increases the quantity number (not beyond `min` and `max` amount).

After reaching min, the `-` button is grayed out. After reaching max, the `+` button is grayed out. A tooltip appears which says `Quantity cant be less than <min>` or `Quantity cant be more than <max>`.

```
if ($button.hasClass("minus") && $quantity <= $("#dropdown").data("min")) {
  $button.addClass("grayout");
  $("#tooltip").html("Quantity can't be less than " + $("#centerbox").html()).show();
} else if ($button.hasClass("plus") && $quantity >= $("#dropdown").data("max")) {
  $button.addClass("grayout");
  $("#tooltip").html("Quantity can't be more than " + $("#centerbox").html()).show();
}
```

I have this if else statement which does the job. Since the contents of if else blocks are almost the same except "less" and "more". Whats the best way to optimize the code?

All elements are created from JS:

```
var $centerBox = $("<div>",{id:"centerbox"});
var $negButton = $("<input>",{type:"button","class":"custombutton minus",value:"-"});
var $posButton = $("<input>",{type:"button","class":"custombutton plus",value:"+" });
```

These three elements are all siblings of a conainer div.
`var $button = $(ev.target);` created from onclick event on the button elements.

Things i have tried (but not yet satisfied):

- Have conditions clubbed by "||" and within the block, check for class again and modify the text accordingly.
- Have a map outside of the function which maps button element to word
- Modify the tooltip text to say `Cant go beyoond the range <min> and <max>`

Comment: It should be possible to optimise this, but could you add the HTML to your question as well please

Comment: Where is this if else statement? is it inside onlick function or what?

Comment: @Henrikki if-else block is within the onclick method.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i have added the script which creates those elements. HTML contains nothing relevent :)

Comment: How about using 2 onClick functions and they each have their own if statement which handles the graying and text, it would make the code more maintainable and readable

Comment: @Henrikki Thanks! but this approach is no different from the one specified in the question. If implemented, it will still have those duplicate lines of code - which i am trying to eliminate.

Comment: Here's my take, but it feels a bit pointless: https://jsfiddle.net/7tgvf4hu/

Comment: I dont know the field of this program but IMHO there is no need for 2 buttons -  and + for this simple operation of choosing quantity for order. Why not just use the dropdown?

Comment: @ChrisG awesome! Thats exactly what i had in mind but not happy with it though.

Comment: @Henrikki dropdown is simple but of less UX. Design guys at office thinks that this approach is kinda more fun :P

Comment: If you're doing somekind of game i understand but if it is normal online shopping site the "add to basket" button is usually enough for handling quantitys what user wants.

Comment: @Henrikki i totally agree. But this is what i was asked to do :)

Comment: Yes, that's the way the cookie crumbles.